# Show data from array to array labels in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, tableview

i have the dictionary - `dictTime: [Int:[Int]]` and I'd like to show it in `tableView` in cell.

To show key in every cell - not a problem, but I'd like to show every element of value of dictionary in "own" `UILabel`, so I created `[UILabel]` and understand that count of UILabel in array must be equal count of elements in value of dictionary, but how to do it in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` for showing for every row (row - it's key-[value])?

Comment: use `numberOfRows(inSection section: Int)` and return your count.

Comment: can you show your dictionary and the actual output you want?

Comment: Who don't you just simply replace `cell.textLabel?.text = indexPath.row` by `cell.textLabel?.text = dictTime[indexPath.row]` in `cellForRowAt` ?

Comment: @Niharika `[1:[1,2,3], 2: [1,2,3]]` and so I have two row (because 2 keys) and every row I'd like to have 3 labels at row and first label has text "1", next - "2", third - "3"

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy i know numbers of rows, because it's count of keys in my dictionary

Comment: [1,2,3] value for each key is static or it will come dynamically?

Comment: @VadimNikolaev so you don't know how to count dictionary values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` call an other function and pass your dictionary value to that function for example `[1,2,3]` also pass your `tbaleviewcell` to that function. Now in that function run a loop on your dictionary array `[1,2,3]` and one by one `UILabel` into your `tableviewcell` programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dictionary is like **[Int1: [Int2]]**, that means:

- dictTime.allKeys will give you array of all Int1
- dictTime[Int1] will give you respective [Int2]

Example:

var dictTime = [1: [1,2], 2: [2,3], 3: [3,4]]

For showing these in a tableView:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dictTime.count
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let keys = Array (dictTime.keys)
        cell.textLabel?.text = String (keys[indexPath.row])
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String (dictTime[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the problem. If you want to have as many rows as dictionary entries, use the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dictTime.count
}
```

If you want to have as many labels in your cell, as entries for each key in your dictionary, you need to implement a complicated solution.

I would suggest creating a "super cell" which has the maximum amount of labels, put them in a stach view, and hide them according to the number of entries.